# Counting measure, integrability

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$. Which of these functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ are integrable?

a. $f(n) = n^{-2}$

b. $f(n) = (-1)^nn^{-1}$

I think that a is integrable and that b is not, is that true?

Comment: Yes, it is because it becomes the series of absolute values

Comment: Ok nice, thanks